# (Swift) How unwrap the optional value properly? Firebase uid returning nil after authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, uid

I'm new to Swift, have a trouble with Firebase UID.

```
  usersReference.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            print(snapshot)
            if snapshot.hasChild((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid)!)
            {
                print("This user already exist")
            //code

                }
```

***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

Please advise, how unwrap it properly? Or maybe something else?

Comment: `(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid)!` will not be nil if you've either created a newUser or signed in an existing user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unwrapping two potentially nil values without first checking to see if they are nil

1. `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!`

The [currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#currentUser) property returns "The currently signed-in user (or null)."

2. `(FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid)!`

To check if the first or second unwrapping is causing the ***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***, restructure your if statement like so:

```
if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser == nil {
    print("no user logged in")
} else if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid == null {
    print("no user id value")
} else if snapshot.hasChild((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.uid)!) {
    print("This user already exist")
} else {
    // code to handle new user
}
```